# Connecting to file share works from iPad but not macOS

Tags: windows, macos, smb, ipad

I am attempting to connect to a Windows file share from macOS 11.3. The IP is 192.168.0.6, however my Mac will ask for username and password. When I enter them, it will shake in error and will not connect.

I know the credentials are correct because my iPad Pro connects to the file share without any issues.

This is what safari shows when I go to the IP:

[image: 192.168.0.6]

Comment: I changed your text a little to signal more strongly this is about a file share. // When you connect from your iPad, do you enter the same credentials?

Comment: @DanielB Thank you! Yes, it is the same credentials. It works fine on iPad but not Mac

Comment: @DanielB any ideas?

Comment: No, sorry. I don't use SMB on my Apple devices.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Hey @WillMays, don’t forget to check harrymc’s answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try the Microsoft RDP App. You would also need to enable RDP connectivity on the server by pressing Win + Pause then clicking Remote Settings on the left.

Comment: The issue is that this is a company server and I have no access to it at all. Just weird how it works on iPad but not the iMac.

Comment: Can you clarify how you're connecting from each device?

Comment: On the iPad I just open Files app and click connect to server, I type in 192.168.0.6, enter my credentials, and it connects just fine. I do the same steps for Mac but it does not work

Comment: Do you have any ideas to get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

According to the post
[Cannot connect to SMB share](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252707743),
this is a regression in macOS 11.3.
This problem didn't exist in macOS 11.2.

The workaround as given in the post was to use SMB2,
as the problem apparently only arrives when using SMB3.

Use the following in Console:

```
echo "[default]" | sudo tee -a /etc/nsmb.conf
echo "protocol_vers_map=2" | sudo tee -a /etc/nsmb.conf
```

Reboot is required.